# Problems posting data to a server using jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm a student who is doing an app with jQueryMobile and gonna be compiled with Phonegap. I want to posting data to a server using jQuery but I have problems loading my .php file in the server.

I have the last version of jQuery.

Here I put my script for post the data from a form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var postData = $('#registerForm').serialize();

        $('#registerForm').submit(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                data: postData,
                url: 'http://www.smartweb.cat/app/Habana/user_register.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('Usuari registrat correctament.');
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Hi ha algun problema amb el registre.');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english wrinting.

Comment: Which problems? Please describe what doesn't work! BTW do not build SQL commands with user inputs: use SQL parameters or any SQL code user will write will be injected into command you execute.

Comment: mysql is being deprecated, you should start using mysqli.

You should also prefer [http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/] (serializeArray)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post data are empty. You retrieve them directly when the DOM is loaded and not when the form is submit. You should move your `var postData`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //var postData = $('#registerForm').serialize();

    $('#registerForm').submit(function() {
        var postData = $('#registerForm').serialize(); // here
        $.ajax({
            //...
       });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to say that you should use prepared statements. 
Althought you sanitize user input(GOOD) its still recommended using prepared statements.
Not only does it help with readability its also more secure.

Make sure your form sends following postdata:

```
{name:"YourName", surname:"Yoursurname",date:"<dateobject>",email:"sample@mail.com",user:"username",password:"password}

== THIS LOOKS OK == 
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);
$surname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["surname"]);
$date = $_POST["date"];
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["user"]);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["pass"]);
enter code here
```

If the conditions above are the same the server should receive all your data. I do see a problem in your query that may be the problem.

What you are doing is inserting everything as string in the database. You have to make sure when you try to execute a query given values for a table that the given values correspond with the database.

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tableName (name, surname, date, email, user, pass) VALUES   
('$name', '$surname', '$date', '$email', '$user', '$pass')"); //insert
```

Make sure everything is correct for example your date column in the database is it a string or a mysql date TYPE. Try to lose the '.

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tableName (name, surname, date, email, user, pass) VALUES   
($name, $surname, $date, $email, $user, $pass)");
```